# React native open default mail app with attachments

Tags: android, ios, react-native, email, email-attachments

I need to be able to open the default email app on the click of a button from a react native application. I tried using [react-native-email-link](https://github.com/leanmotherfuckers/react-native-email-link) but it does not have the option of adding attachments. Is there something else I can use that will allow attachments?

Answer (score 0):

You can likely achieve this with [expo-mail-composer](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/mail-composer/):

```js
    import * as MailComposer from 'expo-mail-composer';

    [...]

    const canMail = await MailComposer.isAvailableAsync();

    if(!canMail) {
      console.warn("Can't open the mail app! You may be using the iPhone simulator or don't have a mail app installed")
      return;
    }

    MailComposer.composeAsync({
      subject: "Hello, Mail Composer!",
      body: "Some body text goes here",
      recipients: "somebody@example.com",
      attachments: [
        "https://venturebeat.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/stack_overflow_logo.jpg?w=1200&strip=all"
        // you can also attach local files
      ]
    });
```

Working Snack demo here: https://snack.expo.dev/@joem-rp/expo-mail-composer-demo